# SQL : exact use of count

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate query for following statement: But I am getting an error. Can anyone correct me ?

Question: how many staffs who are female with salary is higher than 9000.
Query:

```
SELECT sex COUNT(staffNo)
FROM Staff
WHERE salary > 9000;
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: @Aominè added coma but still getting an error

Comment: @pari see Ken's answer.

Comment: I've answered your question, but for future reference: When you post a question that says *I get an error*, that's a meaningless problem description unless you also include information about the error, including the **exact error message**. That message is on the screen right in front of you, and there is absolutely no reason it shouldn't be made available to us as well. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**, and it's in your best interest to give us the details that make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: sure @KenWhite I will follow next time

Comment: I don't get it - your output doesn't show an error. You got the result right there in your question: 2.  It's the first row in a result named count(*)

Comment: One more thing to consider next time. When you added the SQL tag, you were also shown a box that suggested you add a tag for a specific DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.), because syntax and functionality varies between them. Don't ignore that suggestion. In this case there isn't any difference, but in other cases there are major ones, and not telling us which DBMS you're using means it takes longer for you to get an answer because we have to wait until you edit to tell us, or you get wrong answers because they're written for other databases and yours is different.

Comment: @pari also please don't vandalise your post, that is _don't_ change the context of the post.

Comment: I rolled back the question because none of the comments or answers made sense any longer. @Aominè I agree!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you were sort of (not quite) close:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS FemaleStaff
FROM Staff
WHERE sex = 'F' and salary > 9000;
```

It's best to let the database server decide which column to use for the `COUNT()`, and the requirement only asks you to show the number of employees who are female with a salary above 9000, so you don't need any more columns or a GROUP BY to do so.

Comment: For this query I am getting output as shown above. Is it correct ?

Comment: @Aominè: No, there aren't. Actually, my previous comment is wrong. There is one row in my result set, which contains the value `2` in a column named `FemaleStaff`, because there are two female employees (Ann Beech and Susan Brand) who make more than 9000 salary (12000 and 24000 respectively).